# Bad resolution in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: xorg, radeon, display-resolution, 16.04, amd-graphics

I have a problem with Ubuntu 16.04. I have a Philips 192E monitor, which has 1366x768 resolution. My graphic card is a AMD Radeon 265. Unfortunately, after installing Ubuntu (fresh install), the highest resolution available is 1024x764.

I know, this is a question that has been asked tons of times. Me myself have faced this problem in the past. Nonetheless, in this edition of Ubuntu I cannot modify xorg. So I am running out of ideas.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You could try xrandr to add a new resolution.

First, generate a valid xrandr resolution string: `cvt 1366 768 60` (60 is Refresh Rate). You need everything after `Modeline`.

Next, run `xrandr --newmode %string_from_previous_command%`

After that, you should add the resolution to your monitor.

`xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1366x768_60.00` (replace `VGA-0` with your monitor, you can type `xrandr` without any options to see available screens).

Then apply your new mode with:

`xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1366x768_60.00` (again, replace `VGA-0` with your monitor).

That helped me in before when I was using an old AMD videocard.